# ShinyApp automatically changes dataset under a given condition

Tags: r, plot, shiny

I have a shinyApp that produces two different type of plots depending on the data.
This data is exactly the same (variables and columns) except one of them is raw and the other one is discretized.

Right now what I have is an app for which you need to manually change the dataset every time you want to change the type of plot.
So, you will upload one dataset or another (raw or discretized), depending on which plot you want to obtain.

I would like an app that automatically changes the data if you select one type of data or another.

For example, let's say I upload the raw data (iris dataset for example purposes) and I click on `boxplot` for two given variables,
but then, I want to obtain the `barplot` for the discretized version of the same variables, hence the shinyApp should be able to automatically change the datasets.

Is this possible?

Here you have the basic RepEx.

```
# Shiny
library(shiny)

# Data
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)

# Plots
library(ggplot2)




not_sel <- "Not Selected"

ui <- navbarPage(
  tabPanel(
    title = "Plotter",
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        title = "Inputs",
        fileInput("xlsx_input", "Select XLSX file to import", accept = c(".xlsx")),
        selectInput("num_var_1", "Variable X axis", choices = c(not_sel)),
        selectInput("num_var_2", "Variable Y axis", choices = c(not_sel)),
        prettyRadioButtons(
          inputId = "graph_selection",
          label = "Choose:", 
          choices = c("Boxplot", "Barplot")
        ),
        actionButton("run_button", "Run Analysis", icon = icon("play"))
      ),
      mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(
          tabPanel(
            title = "Plot",
            plotOutput("sel_graph")
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)



# Server

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  # Dynamic selection of the data
  data_input <- reactive({
    #req(input$xlsx_input)
    #inFile <- input$xlsx_input
    #read_excel(inFile$datapath, 1)
    iris
  })
  
  # We update the choices available for each of the variables
  observeEvent(data_input(),{
    choices <- c(not_sel, names(data_input()))
    updateSelectInput(inputId = "num_var_1", choices = choices)
    updateSelectInput(inputId = "num_var_2", choices = choices)
  })
  
  num_var_1 <- eventReactive(input$run_button, input$num_var_1)
  num_var_2 <- eventReactive(input$run_button, input$num_var_2)
  

  ## Obtain plots dynamically --------------------------------------------------
  #Boxplot
  draw_boxplot <- function(data_input, num_var_1, num_var_2){
    ggplot(data = data_input, aes(x = .data[[num_var_1]], y = .data[[num_var_2]])) +
      geom_boxplot() + 
      theme_bw()
  }
    ## Barplot
  draw_barplot <- function(data_input, num_var_1, num_var_2){
    ggplot(data = data_input, aes(x = Var1, y = Freq, fill = Var2, label = round(Freq, 3))) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
      ylim(0, 1) +
      theme_bw()
  }
    
  ## BoxPlot -------------------------------------------------------------------
  
  plot_1 <- eventReactive(input$run_button,{
    req(data_input(), num_var_1(), num_var_2())
    draw_boxplot(data_input(), num_var_1(), num_var_2())
  })
  
  # Create another plot for display --------------------------------------------
  plot_2 <- eventReactive(input$run_button,{
    req(data_input(),input$num_var_2)
    draw_barplot(data_input(), num_var_1(), num_var_2())
  })
  
  graphInput <- reactive({
    switch(input$graph_selection,
           "Boxplot" = plot_1(),
           "Barplot" = plot_2()
    )
  })
  
  
  output$sel_graph <- renderPlot(
      graphInput()
  )
 
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Are you asking whether it's possible for Shiny to just find a dataset on its own on your computer, given that the user click some option in the Shiny application? This is how I understand your question.

Comment: Hi @jpiversen, yes, that was my question

Answer (score 0):

So "is it possible for Shiny to find a dataset on its own on your computer, given some user input" - maybe. Under are some possible solutions and considerations.

### If your application will only be used locally

If you only plan to use Shiny locally, it's quite easy to have the user supply a character string for a folder where Shiny could import all the files it needs. As long as the files have a standardized name format, its straightforward to make logic to match the right input with the right plot.

Note that you cannot do this with `fileInput()`, because it only stores the filename, and not the full path to the file.

### If your application might be hosted somewhere

If you want to host your application and don't run it locally it gets worse. Shiny can then only access files on the computer where it's run. Your best option then might be to let the user upload multiple files with `fileInput(..., multiple = TRUE)`. Again, given that the names are standardized, you could make some logic to connect the right data with the right plot.